# cakephp data format inconsitency

Tags: php, cakephp

I see data returned in different formats for different models and I don't know why.

I have the following 2 models defined (I realize the associations don't make complete sense - I changed their context - but the issue exists :) :

```
//
// RecipeItem Model
//
class RecipeItem extends AppModel
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Recipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className' => 'Ingredient',
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
};

//
// Ingredient Model
//
class Ingredient extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'IngredientType' => array(
            'className' => 'IngredientType',
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
};

//
// IngredientType
//
class IngredientType extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className' => 'Ingredient',
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_type_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
};
```

I get my data returned in this format :

```
    "RecipeItem": [
        {
            "id": "16181",
            "recipe_id": "4150",
            "ingredient_id": "6866",
            "amount_in_ounces": "16.00",
            "created": "2014-08-06 21:34:50",
            "modified": "2014-08-06 21:34:50",
            "Ingredient": {
                "id": "6866",
                "ingredient_type_id": "2",
                "user_id": "1",
                "name": "Cinnamon",
                "notes": "Cinnamon spice notes",
                "favorite": "0",
                "created": "2014-07-20 23:13:08",
                "modified": "2014-07-20 23:13:08",
                "IngredientType": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Spice"
                }
            }
        },
    ];
```

when I use Containable in my Controller :

```
$data = $this->Recipe->find( 'first',
            array(
                'contain'   => array(
                    'RecipeItem' => array('Ingredient' => array('IngredientType')),
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Recipe.id' => $this->request['id'],
                    'Recipe.user_id' => $this->request['user_id']
                )
            )
        );
```

But CakePHP returns the default format at times :

```
{
    "Ingredient": {
        "id": "6784",
        "ingredient_type_id": "5",
        "user_id": "1",
        "name": "Cinnamon",
        "notes": "Some notes...",
        "favorite": "0",
        "created": "2014-07-20 23:13:08",
        "modified": "2014-07-20 23:13:08"
    },
    "IngredientType": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Allspice"
    },
    "User": {
        "id": "1",
        "username": "ccampise",
        "password": "3eccc6ad7b84c40434740c782266ec3cced19133",
        "notes": null,
        "created": "2014-05-16 18:27:56",
        "modified": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
},
....
```

at other times when I use the same Containable notation :

```
$data = $this->Ingredient->find( 'first',
    array(
        'contain'   => array('IngredientType'),
    )
);
```

I'm not sure I have a preference, but I do prefer to use *one* or the other, and not both for consistency in my models.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. This function will consistently nest data returned by cake's inconsistent contain results.

```
// model

public function formatData(&$data) 
{
    if (isset($data[0])) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            $this->formatData($data[$key]);
        }
    } else {
        $firstKey = key($data);
        $mainData = reset($data);
        unset($data[key($data)]);
        $data = array($firstKey => array_merge($mainData, $data));
    }   
}

// controller

$this->User->formatData($data);
```

As a side note CakePHP 3 does not seem to suffer from this inadequacy.

Answer (score 0):

This is CakePHP's default behavior, determining on how to place 1-n relations in the result array based on the model you're querying.

If you really want to change this, you can always hook into the `afterFind()`, but it will cause more confusion in the future.

I'm afraid you'll have to get used to this.